# SAS SQL: How to do (group base on Case) without pulling data first?

Tags: sql, sas, query-optimization

I need to count the data of a particular massive table without pulling the data. Normally I group the data and perform a count...

```
select a.type,
       a.color,
       count(a.claimnumber) as count_of_claim
from mytable as a
group by a.type, a.color
```

But in this instance, the color is determined by a `CASE WHEN.. ELSE` statements. Sort of like this: (I made up this example, but the structure of my production problem is same).

```
SELECT b.type, 
       b.color, 
       Count(claimnumber) AS claimnumber_count 
FROM   (
        SELECT a.type, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN a.company = 'honda' 
                      AND Substr(a.modelnum, 1, 5) <> 'AAAAA' THEN 'red' 
                 WHEN Substr(a.modelnum, 1, 6) = 'BBBBBB' THEN 'blue' 
                 WHEN Substr(a.modelnum, 1, 5) = 'CCCCC' THEN 'white' 
                 ELSE 'black' 
                 END AS color, 
               Substr(a.claimnumber, 1, 10) AS claimnumber 
        FROM   mytable AS a
        ) AS b 
GROUP  BY b.type, b.color
```

I am pulling all the data down, determined the color by some When/Else case, and then counting how many there are using group. Is there a way I can simply increment a counter, or do the (grouping) without having this derived table?

I read a lot of questions on stackoverflow, they empathized **do the counting on server side**, and I would like to implement my query as such. My current solution is really slow. It essentially pulling 1 year worth of record and counting them (Over 4-5 hours).

Dummy output of claim count:

```
Type | Color | Count
-------------------
Car    red      16894
Car    blue     2316
Car    black    1560
Car    white    89143 
Bus    red      165
Bus    blue     9611230
Bus    black    25284
Bus    white    16929971
```

Comment: you say this isn't actually your problem but "like" your problem -- in this way it feels like a solution is almost wasted here but I will code one for you.

Comment: basically you need to convert your case to a join.

Comment: Can you confirm if the SQL is running in SAS? Or is the SQL query being performed on a remote database such as SQL server or mySQL?

Comment: Note that when SAS passes the query to the server it will 'translate' it. You can check the provided query using the CALCULATED keyword and see how it performs.

Comment: @Reeza using the calculated keyword seems slower than the original solution, for a smaller sample size, it's about 2-3 times slower (?)

Comment: Wow...ok then. That's not what I would have expected, is there anything else in the query not shown that SAS may not be passing to the server?

Comment: @George You may need to provide more specific information about the query structure and the database server interaction.  You don't actually include any information in the question about that specifically - depending on how you have coded this, you may be forcing SAS to download all of the data first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not hard to group by a derived column. You can just use the column numbers from your variable list in the GROUP BY clause

```
select a.type,
     , a.color
     , count(a.claimnumber) as count_of_claim
from mytable a
group by 1,2
```

If you are really getting performance issues when you replace A.COLOR with a CASE statement then perhaps your database is not optimized to summarize that way?  Your CASE seems to be using only a couple of variables to make the new COLOR column so perhaps you can first summarize by those variables and it will run faster?  If nothing else then you should need to execute fewer SUBSTR() function calls.

```
SELECT a.type
     , CASE WHEN a.company = 'honda'
              AND not (substr(a.modelnum, 1, 5) = 'AAAAA') THEN 'red' 
         WHEN Substr(a.modelnum, 1, 6) = 'BBBBBB' THEN 'blue' 
         WHEN Substr(a.modelnum, 1, 5) = 'CCCCC' THEN 'white' 
         ELSE 'black' 
       END AS color 
     , sum(nobs) as claimnumber_count
FROM (select type,company,modelnum
           , count(claimnumber) as nobs
      from mytable
      group by 1,2,3) a
group by 1,2
```

Comment: This is a super interesting approach, I am coding this up and testing it right now.

Comment: P.S. I never use `<>` as an operator in SAS (or anywhere). In a data step that is the `max` operator, but in SQL it means not equal. Either reformulate to use NOT or use `^=` or `ne` as the operator and avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with the keyword CALCULATED?

Something like the following:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select case when age<13 then 'Pre Teen'
               when age<15 then 'Teen'
               when age>=16 then 'Adult'
               else 'CHECKME'
               end as age_group,
               count(*) as num_age_group
from sashelp.class
group by CALCULATED age_group;
quit;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question -- sashelp.class is not mentioned

Comment: It's a sample that shows how the keyword CALCULATED is used, so it's a solution to the question asked, but not with their sample. Since there's no sample data provided and everyone who has SAS has sashelp.class I typically use those as examples instead.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the case to a join:

```
SELECT a.type, 
       coalesce(b.color,'black') as color, 
       Count(*) AS claimnumber_count 
FROM mytable a
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 'honda' as company, 'AAAAA%' as modelnum, 'red' as color
     UNION ALL
   SELECT null as company, 'BBBBBB%' as modelnum, 'blue' as color
     UNION ALL
   SELECT null as company, 'CCCCC%' as modelnum, 'white' as color
) ON a.company = coalesce(b.company,a.company) AND a.modelnum like b.modelnum
GROUP BY a.type, coalesce(b.color,'black')
```

as I said this might be wasted if yours is actually complex and this does not show you how to do it, but there you go -- "server side" counting.

Comment: @George - should just be more ANDs in the join.

Comment: Yes, I will code it up and do a few testing to compare performance. Because it is a query that used regularly. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with the Join being a good solution, btw, as long as there is a table to get this data from (there should be in an ideal world, but we don't all live there).

Comment: @Joe the actual data are stored in Oracle, would that make a difference?

Comment: @George The question isn't where are the data stored.  The question is whether the information in your `case` statement is already in a table somewhere.  The relationship between `company` , `modelnum`, and `color` - is that in a table, and you're just hardcoding this stuff ?  Or is it not in a table anywhere, it's just logic rules you're writing in code.  Ideally the information would be in a table and you'd use this method rather than a bunch of CASE statements, but if it's not, it may be more work to put it into a table than to do this.

Comment: @Joe The color information is not store in the table anywhere, it's a logic rule that is specific to my reporting. I wish it is already in the table as a column / variable. But I have to calculate it myself.

Comment: @Joe -- I've encountered countless cases where using `UNION ALL` in SQL Server or a `VALUES` statement in Oracle or DB2 to create a table like this on the fly is **much** faster than a case statement.  SQL compilers will make memory based table to join to which is often faster than `CASE`.  It might be harder to type the SQL but it will run faster.

Comment: @Hogan Certainly, and if it makes a big difference in performance I wouldn't be averse to that (if it doesn't over-complicated the code - I don't think I want 30 or 40 `UNION ALL` statements, at that point I would make sure a table was created as part of the process).  In SAS there's actually better ways to do this, but the concept works all the same.

Answer (score 0):

In SAS, you also have the option to refer to columns by number.  This isn't *necessarily* a good idea (from a descriptive code point of view), but it is an option that sometimes is helpful for making code more readable.

However, it doesn't work in most (or any?) other SQL implementations.

Reusing Reeza's example:

```
proc sql;
create table test as
select case when age<13 then 'Pre Teen'
               when age<15 then 'Teen'
               when age>=16 then 'Adult'
               else 'CHECKME'
               end as age_group,
               count(*) as num_age_group
from sashelp.class
group by 1;
quit;
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question sashelp.class is not mentioned in the OQ

Comment: @Hogan It's a useful dataset to provide a simple example, since we don't have a copy of the original dataset.  Please read about [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Ha, rough downvote for a correct and relevant answer. Sheesh.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you could redefine group then count number with case when, you could also redefine group and count number at the same time with sum like this:

```
proc sql;
    select Sex,sum(age<13 ) as Group_1,
           sum(13<=age<15 ) as Group_2,
           sum(age=15) as Group_3, 
           sum(age>=16) as Group_4 
    from sashelp.class
    group by sex;
quit;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question